# Как реализовать уведомление в Android по времени?

Tags: java, android, android-notification

У меня есть приложение с заметками. Я добавил туда уведомления (которые появляются в строке состояния). Для теста я сделал так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Green" приложение не только меняло фон, но и отослало уведомление пользователю. Но мне бы хотелось сделать так, чтобы уведомление отсылалось пользователю не по нажатию кнопку, а автоматически, в определённое время(например, в 17:00) , даже если он не открыл приложение. Как мне это реализовать? Для этого я заранее подготовил BootCompletedReceiver чтобы автоматически запускать приложение после загрузки устройства. Код ресивера и отправки уведомления будет ниже.

BootCompletedReceiver:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public BootCompletedReceiver() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

        }
    }
}
```

Код для отправки уведомления:

```
...

public void onClickGreen(View view) { 
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {
            
            v.vibrate(500);
        }
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Options.this, Options.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Options.this,
                0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(Options.this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ikon_for_calendar_1)
                        .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                        .setContentText("Пора проверить заметки!")
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)

                        .setAutoCancel(true); // автоматически закрыть уведомление после нажатия



        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(Options.this);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, builder.build());


    }
```

Comment: Правильно такие вещи делать через push notification с сервера. Чтобы приложение не болталось в памяти и не жрало батарею только ради того чтобы однажды какое-то уведомление отобразить. Вместо этого сервер отправить пуш когда надо, система запустит приложение и отобразит уведомление.

Comment: Понятно, что с пушами все усложняется, без них можно все сделать с помощью WorkManager, он умеет пережить перезагрузки телефона и все такое. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: Делайте через AlarmManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте alarm manager и поместите свое уведомление в класс NotifyService

```
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Current.this , NotifyService.class);     
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ThisApp.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
   calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
   calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);  
   //set repeating every 24 hours
```